# K2 BlackPearl User, Roles, Groups Validation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, k2, infopath2010

Is there a way to check if the requester of a document using the InfoPath form is the proponent and further check if that user is the division head?

I can't seem to find  a component on this under the Events Wizards.

I used these tutorials as references: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rx3Y-c6D_7k&feature=player_embedded) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oanH3xkIoO4&feature=related).

I have here a screenshot on this issue.
[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "proponent"? 
This is definately not something that you will be able to do with the event wizards, BUT I would suggest you save this data somewhere in a smart object and then use a smart object event to read the data. 
So your smart object will look something like this:

User Smart Object
Properties:
 - Username,
 - IsProponent
 - IsDivisionHead
 - etc

Now when you look up this smart object with a load operation using the username as an input, you can see if IsProponent = true and IsDivisionHead = true.